# AC_CONFIG_FILES not generating Makefiles

Tags: makefile, autotools

I'm writing an app in Vala with support to plugins. The app has the following directory structure:

```
data/
    [data files]

m4/
    my_project.m4

plugins/
    example/
        example.plugin.in
        example-plugin.vala
        Makefile.am
po/
src/
    [source files]
```

The file "my_project.m4" dinamically adds plugin dirs with a simple defined function called MYPROJ_ADD_PLUGIN, and it works fine as I tested it with some other projects. Basically, it calls:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([plugins/example/Makefile])
[...]
AC_CONFIG_FILES([plugins/example/example.plugin])
```

The problem is, when I try to configure it, it gives back:

```
"error: cannot find input file: `plugins/example/Makefile.in'"
```

The example makefile (plugins/example/Makefile.am) is the following:

```
include $(top_srcdir)/common.am

plugin_LTLIBRARIES = example-plugin.la
plugin_DATA = example.plugin

example_plugin_la_SOURCES = \
    example-plugin.vala

example_plugin_la_VALAFLAGS = \
    $(MYPROJ_COMMON_VALAFLAGS) \
    --target-glib=2.38

example_plugin_la_CFLAGS = \
    $(MYPROJ_COMMON_CFLAGS) \
    -I$(srcdir) \
    -DG_LOG_DOMAIN='"Example"'

example_plugin_la_LIBADD = \
    $(MYPROJ_COMMON_LIBS)

example_plugin_la_LDFLAGS = \
    $(MYPROJ_PLUGIN_LINKER_FLAGS) \
    -lm

EXTRA_DIST = example.plugin.in
```

Every var is correctly generated (in common.am and configure.ac).

I appreciate any advice on this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `AC_CONFIG_FILES` has to be called by `configure` - i.e., they are [A]uto[C]onf macros that belong in `configure.ac`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer to my own question. Apparently, everything I had to do was add a "lib" prefix to my plugin output file. The plugins/example/Makefile.am now looks like:

```
include $(top_srcdir)/common.am

plugin_LTLIBRARIES = **lib**example.la
plugin_DATA = example.plugin

**lib**example_la_SOURCES = \
    example-plugin.vala

**lib**example_la_VALAFLAGS = \
    $(MYPROJ_COMMON_VALAFLAGS) \
    --target-glib=2.38

**lib**example_la_CFLAGS = \
    $(MYPROJ_COMMON_CFLAGS) \
    -I$(srcdir) \
    -DG_LOG_DOMAIN='"Example"'

**lib**example_la_LIBADD = \
    $(MYPROJ_COMMON_LIBS)

**lib**example_la_LDFLAGS = \
    $(MYPROJ_PLUGIN_LINKER_FLAGS) \
    -lm

EXTRA_DIST = example.plugin.in
```

This was the only modification I did, and it works as expected now. Seems like autoconf/autotools is very rigid about the syntax of plugins and shared libs, as they MUST start with *lib* prefix.